# ¿Que charset debo usar cuando mando un mail por PHP?

Tags: php, email

Uso este `charset`:

```
   $mailHeader2 .= "Mime-Version: 1.0 \r\n";
   $mailHeader2 .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8";
```

Comment: ¿Qué problema sucede cuando usas ese charset? ¿Qué dificultades tienes? Por favor agrega más información en tu pregunta de manera que podamos entender mejor tu problema y brindarte una mejor ayuda.

Comment: Cuando se envía el mail los caracteres como á é í ó ú Ñ ! los remplaza por un rombo con símbolo de pregunta así -> �

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Imaginando que tu problema se relaciona a caracteres con tildes y eñes, es muy probable que debas utilizar el charset UTF-8.

Utilizando la información de [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2265626/1065197), este sería el código de tu header:

```
$mailHeader2 .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8";
```

Y si el contenido de tu correo no posee ningún HTML, entonces puedes usar este header:

```
$mailHeader2 .= "Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8";
```

Asimismo, asegúrate que el charset de tu archivo PHP sea el mismo que el que estás colocando en el header. Esto es, si vas a enviar el email en UTF-8, tu archivo PHP también debe estar escrito en UTF-8.

Comment: Tiene contenido html, asi que no puedo ponerlo como 
$mailHeader2 .= "Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8";
Coloca en el correo el codigo y el utf-8 es el que estoy utilizando actualmente pero me coloca  � en vez de í o algun caracter

Comment: Si tienes contenido HTML, utiliza el primero...

Comment: como comente utf-8 es el que estoy utilizando actualmente pero me coloca � en vez de í o algun caracter

Comment: En tu pregunta (desde antes que fuese editada) explicas que utilizas charset ISO-8859-1, no UTF-8. Quizás el archivo .php no está en utf-8. Te recomiendo que revises esto con un editor de texto.

Comment: Cierto era eso. Gracias Luiggi

Answer (score 1):

`charset=utf-8`, ya que contiene todos los caracteres del lenguaje español.